# can anyone proide me 4 legged robot urdf/xacro for my project?

Tags: ros, collada-urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make a 4 legged robot and move it it gazebo simulator. although i have learned how to make it by using blender, meshlab and gazebo+ros tutorials, if someone has already made one than my time will be saved. The main task here i'm trying to do  is make an algorithm to move / run and keep it stable in every move so that it can walk in any kind of path. So if anyone have already made such robot which has got all the properties to be simulated in gazebo like proper inertia values, collision elements, visual elements u can help me by giving me that file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269841/can-anyone-proide-me-4-legged-robot-urdf/xacro-for-my-project?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tested, but this [LittleDog](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/LittleDog)  maybe will work for you.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0